# crystal report between 2 dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

How can I show filtered data between two dates in crystal report on web? I tried to search for solutions but most of them are made in VB and on Windows application. I can display all the records in the database but when filtering it between date ranges it doesn't show the filtered data.

Here's my aspx

```
<div align="center">
        Enter Date from: <asp:TextBox ID="Start_date" type="date"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        Enter Date to: <asp:TextBox ID="End_Date" type="date"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
 </div> 

    <div>            
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
    </div>
```

I already tried to use stored procedures, I saw one that I need to use a parameter but I don't have any idea how to do that

Comment: How do you retrieve report data? what is your datasource?

Comment: its very simple. are you added procedure with 2 parameter, if yes, then import in Crystal report by assign data-source and put some fields to show proper data, then just f5 its ask both dates , enter it and show the data. if this is proper, then link with c# code and pass both textbox dates to Cr parameter

Comment: the problem is already solved by using parameters inside crystal report, but when i tried to export it to excel, nothing happens